# File doesn't exist! in wordpress function.php file while creating new post or page

Tags: wordpress

```
function wp_json_file_decode( $filename, $options = array() ) {
$result   = null;
$filename = wp_normalize_path( realpath( $filename ) );
if ( ! file_exists( $filename ) ) {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            /* translators: %s: Path to the JSON file. */
            __( "File %s doesn't exist!" ),
            $filename
        )
    );
    return $result;
}

$options      = wp_parse_args( $options, array( 'associative' => false ) );
$decoded_file = json_decode( file_get_contents( $filename ), $options['associative'] );

if ( JSON_ERROR_NONE !== json_last_error() ) {
    trigger_error(
        sprintf(
            /* translators: 1: Path to the JSON file, 2: Error message. */
            __( 'Error when decoding a JSON file at path %1$s: %2$s' ),
            $filename,
            json_last_error_msg()
        )
    );
    return $result;
}

return $decoded_file;
```

}

i have been working on wordpress website,

1. cant able to create new post
2. cant able to create new page[image]
3. is there any plugin errors

Comment: As you haven't shared any code, it's difficult to provide help. Did you check **which** file is missing? Maybe it's a core file that you could find in Wordpress's repository?

Comment: Check the above question now, i have edited the question with code

Comment: You forgot to share what you've tried to resolve the problem

Comment: Some other software in your WordPress  installation calls the function you showed us (a core function) mentioning a filename. But the function can't find the file. It would be wise for you figure out what calls your function and what filename it mentions. If you [edit] your question to tell us that, we may be able to help you.

Comment: i just tried adding new posts and pages in wordpress admin dashboard, i am not familiar with php

Comment: Is this related to programming then? Maybe the folks at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ could help better if this is solely about the usage of Wordpress?

Comment: i dont know wether its related to coding, but not able add new posts/pages